# Is it possible to change Firebase accounts within a single app after build?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to use different Firebase accounts (with different emails) within the same iOS project. The account to be used will be determined after build, at launch. I know that typically I need to include a `GoogleService-Info.plist`. Since I won't know which account I'm using until runtime (credentials will be specified from my backend), I won't be able to include this file before build. I might be able to download it from my server and add it to the bundle. Would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Custom options**

You can use this initializer

```
/**
 * Initializes a customized instance of FIROptions with required fields. Use the mutable properties
 * to modify fields for configuring specific services.
 */
FirebaseOptions.init(googleAppID:gcmSenderID:)
```

create options with info from server

```
let options = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID:"appId", gcmSenderID:"senderId")!
// set other mutable properties here
options.apiKey = ""
options.bundleID = ""
options.clientID = ""
options.databaseURL = ""
options.googleAppID = ""
// and others you have in GoogleService-Info.plist

// and then just configure
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
```

In this case I think it would be better to turn off swizzling

> by adding the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled in the app’s Info.plist file and setting it to NO (boolean value)

**2. Save file**

```
do {
    let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
    let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("GoogleInfo.plist")
    let data = Data() // get data from your plist
    try data.write(to: fileURL)

    let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)!
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

more info here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client